# Why is this not correct? (Independent events))

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we do 2 independent dice rolls with events $A = \{6\}$ and $B = \{6\}$. For the formula for the probability of two independent events we have:

$$\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A) \cdot \mathbb{P}(B)$$

Since $(A \cap B)$ is $\{6\}$
It should be:
$\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A) \cdot \mathbb{P}(B) \Leftrightarrow \mathbb{P}(6) = \mathbb{P}(6) \cdot \mathbb{P}(6) \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{36}$
which is obviously wrong. Where is my mistake?

Comment: In general, one has $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B\mid A)$ which happens to be equivalent to $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B)$ if and only if they are independent events.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about what the probability space is. Since there are two die rolls, the probability space must consist of ordered pairs $(x,y)$, where $x$ is the first roll and $y$ is the second. The outcomes in your probability space must describe the entire situation.

If you let $A$ be the event that the first die is $6$, then 
$$
A=\{(6,1),(6,2),\dots,(6,6)\}
$$
has $6$ outcomes, while 
$$
B = \{(1,6),(2,6),\dots,(6,6)\}
$$
also has $6$ outcomes. Then
$$
A\cap B=\{(6,6)\}
$$
and you now see that $$\frac1{36}=P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)=\frac6{36}\cdot \frac6{36}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$P(A\cap B)= P$(1.st dice is $6$ and 2.nd dice is $6) = {1\over 36}$

and it is not $P(A\cap B) = P($ one dice is $6)$.

Comment: How did you calculate $1/36$ without using $\mathbb{P}(A) \cdot \mathbb{P}(B)$

Comment: Well you have just one good even (both are 6) among 36 events.